# mask java jsoup web crawler as google bot to download web pages

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm using Jsoup in my web crawler. This is the code i use to download web pages.

```
String ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/12.0.742.122 Safari/534.30";
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent(ua).timeout(20000).get(); 
Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
```

How can i mask my java program as a googlebot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following `userAgent`

> Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)

[Read More](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1061943?hl=en)